# Lua: Timer for a Phase within a Recursive Function

Tags: recursion, timer, lua, coronasdk

So I've got a situation. I understand the timer.perforWithDelay but it seems to get exponentially faster since I have a recursive function call to loop a phase. So our game displays an object on screen and you have to swipe it to the correct location. I have the game running all except for one thing: the timer. I want maybe a 5 second timer each time a shape pops up starting after the first object phase begins. Here is my code:

```
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()
physics.setGravity(0,0)

local game_sound = audio.loadStream( "GameScreenAudio.mp3" )
local sound = audio.loadStream( "splashMusic.mp3" )
audio.play(game_sound, {loops = -1} )
function scene:create( event )
local group = self.view


--LOAD IN BACKGROUND AND LOCATE IT TO FIT----------------------------------------------------
local background = display.newImage("game_background.png")

background.x = display.contentWidth / 2
background.y = display.contentHeight / 2
group:insert( background )
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Screen GUI---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local back_triangle = display.newImage("back_triangle.png")
back_triangle.x = display.contentWidth * .87
back_triangle.y = display.contentHeight * .5
back_triangle.xScale = .7; back_triangle.yScale = .7
back_triangle.alpha = .4

local back_diamond = display.newImage("back_diamond.png")
back_diamond.y = display.contentHeight * .5
back_diamond.x = display.contentWidth * .1
back_diamond.xScale = .7; back_diamond.yScale = .7
back_diamond.alpha = .4

local back_circle = display.newImage("back_circle.png")
back_circle.x = display.contentWidth * .5
back_circle.y = display.contentHeight * .1
back_circle.xScale = .7; back_circle.yScale = .7
back_circle.alpha = .35

local back_rectangle = display.newImage("back_rectangle.png")
back_rectangle.x = display.contentWidth * .5
back_rectangle.y = display.contentHeight * .9
back_rectangle.xScale = .7; back_rectangle.yScale = .7
back_rectangle.alpha = .4

group:insert( back_triangle )
group:insert( back_diamond )
group:insert( back_circle )
group:insert( back_rectangle )

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--Load in Images-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--GOOD
-- local excellent = display.newImage("excellent.png")
-- local incredible = display.newImage("incredible.png")
-- local wicked = display.newImage("wicked.png")
-- local good_for_you = display.newImage("good4you.png")
-- local amazing = display.newImage("amazing.png")
-- local spectacular = display.newImage("spectacular.png")
-- local groovy = display.newImage("groovy.png")
-- local stupendous = display.newImage("stupendous.png")
-- local class_act = display.newImage("classact.png")
-- local top_notch = display.newImage("topnotch.png")
-- local yea_man = display.newImage("yeaman.png")
-- local slayer = display.newImage("slayer.png")

-- --BAD
-- local wrecked = display.newImage("wrecked.png")
-- local atrocious = display.newImage("atrocious.png")
-- local bummer = display.newImage("bummer.png")
-- local unacceptable = display.newImage("unacceptable.png")
-- local wretched = display.newImage("wretched.png")
-- local despicable = display.newImage("despicable.png")
-- local revolting = display.newImage("revolting.png")
-- local fail = display.newImage("fail.png")
-- local wrong = display.newImage("wrong.png")
-- local nope = display.newImage("nope.png")

-- imageList_GOOD = {excellent, incredible, wicked, good_for_you, amazing, spectacular, groovy, stupendous, class_act, top_notch, yea_man, slayer} 
-- imageList_BAD = {wrecked, atrocious, bummer, unacceptable, wretched, despicable, revolting, fail, wrong, nope}

imageList_GAME = {"triangle.png", "circle.png", "rectangle.png", "diamond.png"}
------------------------1--------------2---------------3----------------4-----------------------

    local score = 0
    local streak = 0
    local strikes = 0
    local status = nil
    local neg_streak = 0
    local timeLimit = 5

    local score_text = display.newText("Score: ", display.contentWidth*.10, display.contentHeight*.98, native.systemFontBold, 20)
    group:insert( score_text )


function gameFunction()
    local game_number = math.random(1 , 4)


    local shape = display.newImage(imageList_GAME[game_number])
    shape.x = display.contentWidth * .5
    shape.y = display.contentHeight * .5
    local occupied = true
    group:insert( shape )

    --CREATE BACK BUTTON WITH FUNCTIONALITY---------------------------------------------------------
    local back_button = display.newImage("back_button.png")
    back_button.x = display.contentWidth * .93
    back_button.y = display.contentHeight * .945
    back_button.xScale = .25; back_button.yScale = .25



    function back_button:tap(event)
        if strikes < 3 then
            shape:removeSelf()
            composer.removeScene("game" )
            local options = 
            {
                effect = 'fromLeft',
                time = 400
            }
            audio.pause(game_sound)
            audio.play(sound)
            composer.gotoScene( "splash" , options)
        elseif strikes == 3 then
        end

    end
    back_button:addEventListener( "tap", back_button )
    group:insert( back_button )

    local score_points = display.newText(score, display.contentWidth* .30, display.contentHeight*.98, native.systemFontBold, 18)
    group:insert( score_points )

    physics.addBody(shape, "dynamic")
    local motion = nil

    -- touch listener function
    function shape:touch( event )

        local shape = event.target
        if event.phase == "began" then
            shape.previousX = shape.x
            shape.previousY = shape.y

        elseif event.phase == "moved" then
            shape.x = (event.x - event.xStart) + shape.previousX
            shape.y = (event.y - event.yStart) + shape.previousY
        elseif event.phase == "ended" and strikes < 3  then
            getPositionStatus()
            applyForce2Object()
            back_button:removeSelf()
            score_points:removeSelf()
            timeLimit = 5           
            gameFunction()
        end 
    end

    shape:addEventListener( "touch", shape )




    function getPositionStatus()
--SCORING-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if game_number == 1 and shape.x > display.contentWidth * .6 then
            status = "correct"
            score = score + 100
            streak = streak + 1
            neg_streak = 0
        elseif game_number == 2 and shape.y < display.contentHeight * .4 then
            status = "correct"
            score = score + 100
            streak = streak + 1
            neg_streak = 0
        elseif game_number == 3 and shape.y > display.contentHeight * .6 then
            status = "correct"
            score = score + 100
            streak = streak + 1
            neg_streak = 0
        elseif game_number == 4 and shape.x < display.contentWidth * .4 then
            status = "correct"
            score = score + 100
            streak = streak + 1
            neg_streak = 0
        else
            status = "incorrect"
            score = score - 100
            streak = 0
            neg_streak = neg_streak - 1
            strikes = strikes + 1
        end
        print("Status: " , status)
        print("Score: " , score)
        print("Strikes: " , strikes)
    end

    function applyForce2Object()
            --What did user do?-------------------------------
            if shape.x > display.contentWidth * .6 then
                shape:applyForce(2000, 0, shape.x, shape.y)
            elseif shape.y > display.contentHeight * .6 then
                shape:applyForce(0, 2000, shape.x, shape.y)
            elseif shape.y < display.contentHeight * .35 then
                shape:applyForce(0, -2000, shape.x, shape.y)
            elseif shape.x < display.contentWidth * .35 then
                shape:applyForce(-2000, 0, shape.x, shape.y)
            end  
    end

    if strikes == 3 then
        shape:removeSelf()
        print("*********GAME OVER************")
    end
end 
gameFunction()


end  --CREATE scene end


scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )

return scene
```

So with my code, and the recursive function it calls, how can I get a timer to work properly for 5 seconds each time an object appears on the screen. If the object isn't swiped in time I need to add a strike and remove 100 points. Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner. For our intro to Information to Technology class here at college we were given an assignment to create an app using Corona SDK with Lua after having not a single bit of practice using Lua. I'm sure you'll discover this by reading through the code. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that only one shape is shown at a time, the code for the timer goes inside the function that shows that shape, as I read thru your code, thats inside the `gameFunction()`
in which the code for back_button is there also, which is wrong, I suggest that you separate it. Another suggestion is that make another display group for every object you have in the UI, lets say for the UI this includes: Score text, Strikes text, etc. Make another group for the shape, you to have be fully aware of the design hierarchy of your game, separate them. 
Back to the timer code, Do it like this

```
local gameTimer -- forward reference
local timeLimit = 5

local function = timerListener()
  --handles timer event
  timeLimit = timeLimit - 1
  --here you can print the time

  if (timeLimit == 0) then
    --time's up
    timer.cancel(gameTimer)
    gameTimer = nill --we clear it out
    timerLimit = 5 --reset the timer back to 5
    --in here you can print that the player has strike.
    --anything you want to do when the player failed to move the shape
  end
end

gameFunction()
  --code to show the shape
  gameTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, timerListener , 5) 
end --end of gameFunction
```

Then, when the player moved the shape either right or wrong, just do what you did when the time is up, cancel it, nill, then reset the time.
You can put it in another function like:

```
local function resetTimer()
    timer.cancel(gameTimer)
    gameTimer = nill
    timerLimit = 5
end
```

then just call it out.

and one more thing, if you having a hard time removing the shape, on the screen, as I suggested, that put them in a separate group, just clear the the group, and for the event listener, just the the eventListener in that group also, since only one shape is shown. This will change if you are showing many shapes in screen, since you have to take it reference inside the group stack

Happy coding :)